# object data editting form

Tags: python, django

I'm making django app which allow me to study. It has multiple tests with multiple question each. Every question has one correct answer. I'm trying to make form which allow me to edit answer If I made mistake in passing correct answer during making question.

That's what I have already made:

```
models.py

class Question(models.Model):

    text = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)

    def get_answer(self):
        return self.answer_set.all()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text

class Answer(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='parent')
    def __str__(self):
         return self.text
```

```
forms.py

class AnswerEditForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Answer
        exclude = ('question',)
```

```
views.py

def UpdateAnswerView(request, pk):
    form = AnswerEditForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AnswerEditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
            
            obj.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'exam/update_answer.html', context)
```

```
urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    ~some other urls~
    path('answer/edit/<int:pk>/', views.UpdateAnswerView, name='update-answer'), 

]
```

while I'm trying to edit answer i'm getting `Question matching query does not exist.` error.
Where did i make mistake ?

Comment: where is Question model?

Comment: @eisanahardani I've just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `pk` is `None`.
it is better you check your `pk`

```
def UpdateAnswerView(request, pk):
    form = AnswerEditForm()

    if request.method == 'POST' and pk is not None:
        form = AnswerEditForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            try:
               obj.question = Question.objects.get(id=pk)
               obj.save()
               return redirect('home')
            except Question.DoesNotExist:
               pass
          

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'exam/update_answer.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that `pk` is actually getting passed to `UpdateAnswerView`.  Also confirm that you're actually passing a `Question` ID and not an `Answer` ID.